# MediaElement doesnt play

Tags: xamarin.forms

Hello I am trying to use MediaElement XamarinToolkit.I need to use it in the static class and really don't want to use it in my xaml. I have tried several URL but i get no exception, no error nothing it just simply doesn't play. The output says nothing either. I am starting to think that is not possible not to have it in xaml

```
 <application android:label="App2.Android" android:theme="@style/MainTheme"  android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" ></application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="App2.MainPage">
    <StackLayout>
        <Frame BackgroundColor="#2196F3" Padding="24" CornerRadius="0">
            <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="White" FontSize="36"/>
        </Frame>
        <Button Clicked="Button_Clicked" Text="TET"></Button>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace App2
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AudioPlayer.Play("https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3"); // change this to the name of your audio file
        }
        protected override void OnDisappearing()
        {
            base.OnDisappearing();
        }
    }
}

using Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer;
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.UI.Views;

namespace App2
{
    public static class AudioPlayer
    {
        private static readonly MediaElement _mediaElement = new MediaElement();
        private static readonly ConcurrentQueue<string> _mediaQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();
        private static bool _isPlaying = false;

        static AudioPlayer()
        {
            _mediaElement.MediaEnded += OnMediaEnded;
            //_mediaElement.MediaFailed += OnMediaFailed;
        }

        public static void Play(string url)
        {
            _mediaQueue.Enqueue(url);
            if (!_isPlaying)
            {
                PlayNext();
            }
        }

        public static void Pause()
        {
            _mediaElement.Pause();
        }

        public static void Stop()
        {
            _mediaElement.Stop();
        }

        private static async void PlayNext()
        {
            _isPlaying = true;
            if (_mediaQueue.TryDequeue(out string url))
            {
                _mediaElement.Source = new Uri(url);
                _mediaElement.Play();
            }
            else
            {
                _isPlaying = false;
            }
        }

        private static void OnMediaEnded(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PlayNext();
        }

        private static void OnMediaFailed(object sender, Exception e)
        {
            PlayNext();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [MediaElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/views/mediaelement) is a control for playing video and audio. And it should be set in xaml or code behind.

Answer (score 0):

MediaElement must be present in the Xaml or set to the content in the ContentPage to play media.

MediaElement is a XAML control that is used to displays and plays audio and video content. It supports audio and video playback with features such as play, pause, stop, rewind, fast-forward, volume control, and more.

Use MediaElement if you need to play audio or video content with visuals. MediaPlayer can be used to play audio or video content with no visual component, if that's all you need.